# Is it possible to change column type in a materialized view?

Tags: postgresql, materialized-views

I'm pretty sure it's not:

```
ALTER MATERIALIZED VIEW myview ALTER COLUMN quantity SET TYPE integer;
```

produces:

```
ERROR:  "myview" is not a table, composite type, or foreign table
```

But just wanted to check I hadn't [missed something in the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-altermaterializedview.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The data type of a column in a materialized view is derived from the SELECT statement that is stored alongside the mview.

To change the data type of such a column you need to add the appropriate `cast` inside the SELECT and then refresh the mview.